# How to Resolve jQuery conflict when WOW Slider Implemented on Web Page

Tags: jquery

I have a site at http://integritywoodcrafts.com/

There is a WOW Slider Style sheet `<link href="/slider/engine2/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` and the presence of the `jQuery engine` that powers the WOW Slider.

My site has a mouseover menu that works whenever the WOW Slider Style Sheet and the jQuery engine is not present -- see any page in the site except the home page.

Yet, on the Home Page, when the WOW Slider Style Sheet and the jQuery engine is present, the mouseover menus do not function.

I have narrowed the issue down to the jQuery engine being the thing that causes the mouseover menus to not work properly.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing the issue and how I might correct it?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using jQuery noConfilct - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: please post your navigation bar code.

Comment: It's a Magento site. I did not build the menu bar.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script> just like that @eskimo?

Comment: Basically you call the `noConflict()` function, and then use **jQuery** instead of **$**, for example `jQuery(".mydiv")...` instead of `$(".mydiv")...`

Comment: Ok, thanks @eskimo. I'll work on that and see what I can get.

Comment: No problem @H.Ferrence, I'm pretty sure that is the problem, I see the menu is using prototype.js. Google "example jquery noConflict" I'm sure you will find some good examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost certainly prototype and jQuery conflicting.

To resolve it use jQuery `noConfict()` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/))

Your wowslider is being called [here](http://integritywoodcrafts.com/slider/engine2/script.js), and it is already using **jQuery** instead of **$**, so simply putting `$.noConflict();` after your references to the other libraries and jQuery script references should resolve the problem, assuming that the wow slider is the only thing on the page using jQuery

As for the z-index problem, put this in somewhere:

```
#nav                     {z-index: 100;}
#wowslider-container2    {z-index: 1;}
.ws-title                {z-index: 1;}
```

[image]

Should be working 100%

Comment: Thanks @eskimo. I am getting closer. The mouseover menus do not appear over the rotator images. But if you simply keep the mouse hovered over the menu bar and watch closely, you can see the pulldown menu appear momentarily between image transition. Do you have any other suggestions? I appreciate your insight and help.

Comment: Yes @eskimo, I added the following:
`<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery.noConflict();
 var $j = jQuery;
</script>`
I can see the menu during image transitions only

Comment: looks like a z-index issue now. Try setting the z-index of the drop downs higher than that of the image slider

Comment: I had done that before posting here. I think I got all the blocks identified and I have the menus at 10 and the rotator at 9 @eskimo

Comment: Ok, cool...I will do that in about an hour and post back. Thanks for all your help @eskimo.

Comment: You're a huge star @eskimo. Thank you for all your help!